# PayPal gateway has rejected request. You can not do a partial refund on this transaction (#10009: Transaction refused)

Tags: php, paypal, transactions

I'm doing partial refund in my sandbox account. What i'm missing? If i use other credentials then it works fine.

I'm getting below

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. You can not do a partial refund
>   on this transaction (#10009: Transaction refused)

Comment: This usually happens if the transaction is on hold for some reason.  Do you have Payment Review enabled on your Sandbox account?  If so, you probably need to log into the merchant's account on the Sandbox, pull up the transaction details, and hit the "Accept" button -- you should be able to do a partial refund after that.

Comment: Hi @MattCole Thanks for reply. Can we face same issue on LIVE or it's only applicable to Sandbox?

Comment: It can happen on live as well.

Comment: Hi @MattCole. So what are the settings required for that. Same Payment Review should be Enabled?

Comment: Things I know of that can cause a transaction to be held: (a) Risk Controls/Fraud Management Filters (if you turned them on in your account), (b) transactions in a currency you don't hold (if the "Allow payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold" setting is set to "Ask Me"), (c) transactions that are waiting for an eCheck to complete (if the setting to block eChecks is turned off), (d) transactions that are being disputed, or (e) transactions held by PayPal.  You can't really do much to prevent (d) or (e), but you can adjust your account settings to prevent the others.

Comment: HI @MattCole Thanks for reply. If u can answer all points then will accept ur answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things I know of that can cause a transaction to be held:

1. Risk Controls/Fraud Management Filters (if you turned them on in your account),
2. Transactions in a currency you don't hold (if the "Allow payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold" setting is set to "Ask Me"),
3. Transactions that are waiting for an eCheck to complete (if the setting to block eChecks is turned off),
4. Transactions that are being disputed, or
5. Transactions held by PayPal.

You can't really do much to prevent (d) or (e), but you can adjust your account settings to prevent the others.